# apache redirect except some files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a file structure like this:

[image]

my goal is to redirect every request to public/index.php

This is what I have in my current root `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ public/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

it redirects everything, but then my link to css file stops working. The response header for css file shows `Content-Type:text/html`, so I suspect its the htaccess has messed up my `content-type`

My goal: simply deny access to app folder and redirect all to public/index.php (except js/css types of files)

**update**:
I also found this line in my chrome console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would combine the rule you have with rules that don't redirect if the file or directory exists:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

If you really only want js/css files to be ignored, you could say:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.(js|css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried the first rule before but it doesn't redirect me to public/index.php, I upload a new picture to indicate my file structure for a better look. maybe theres some problem with my file structure. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: So did you try the second one? What was the outcome?

Comment: yea I tried the second one, it had no effect though..i used xampp and never touch on the conf

Comment: @Andrew What URL are you requesting? (Please add an example URL to your question.) Presumably your JS/CSS files are real files on the filesystem? Do they have `.js` and `.css` file extensions respectively?

Comment: @w3d yes, they are real file with either .js or .css and I would call it like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xxx.css">` in my header.tpl.php. It works when I remove the rules, which response header receives correctly. I will upload a picture if it helps

Comment: Yes, but what is the URL of your request? Your `/public` folder looks like it's your document root? In which case it should be omitted from the `RewriteRule` substitution. (?)

Comment: @w3d hi, sorry for the late reply. magic folder will be the document root and public will be..public_html, and all the logic will be sealed in app. I kinda follow the Laravel pattern haha..

Comment: @arco444 I just thought to clean up the cache and your second rule works now!! thanks!! I alter a bit to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$`, is there any difference?

Comment: @Andrew "magic folder will be the document root and public will be..public_html" - that is very unusual. "public_html" is (nearly) always the document root - as defined in the server config?!

Comment: There really shouldn't be any difference between those two `RewriteCond` directives (the end of the TestString should be the same in both cases).

Comment: @w3d I was thinking to to put the whole thing into public_html without messing too many privilege and use htaccess to control file overall..anyways its still on production level...For some reason, the first rule didnt do the redirect for me, but I still dont know why..